# Why do they ship a metal sheet with the breadboard?

Tags: esd, breadboard

My breadboard came with a metal sheet:

[image: Breadboard with metal sheet]

The breadboard should hardly be ESD sensitive. And if it would be, then there's still the double sided tape separating the breadboard from the metal sheet. From a cost perspective, I'd say they could just not ship it at all. It does not have a connector, so it's also hard (well, harder than using a breadboard) to connect it to something if it shall serve as a ground or shielding.

Why do they ship it with a metal sheet? What's the purpose of that metal sheet?

Am I supposed to use it? If so, how? Why was it glued to the packaging with two small glue points? If I shall use it, why not stick it into the packaging loosely?

Comment: [Someone on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/ludext/my_solderless_breadboard_came_with_a_thin_sheet/) seems to have bought the same thing. They too believe it's for mechanical stability. I'd say that the metal plate is supposed to be held against your forehead to keep it cool why you troubleshoot yet another breadboard-caused problem, when you could be troubleshooting one actually caused by your design instead... :)  Or maybe it's there to increase the value of the electronics recycling, which is the natural next stop for any breadboard.

Answer (score 1):

Two purposes:

- Mechanical support  / solid backing
- Crude RF shielding (if connected to ground)

Comment: I doubt it is grounded to the breadboard since that would be dangerous if someone goofs up their experiment or just holds the thing in their hand while fiddling around with some circuit.

Comment: @Lundin, A ground *plane* does not have to make DC contact.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik How else are you gonna ground it? Create a separate wire? And the same concerns with safety remain no matter. It's actually more dangerous to ground it externally because of larger potential differences.

Comment: @Lundin it's not grounded to the bb once mounted since there's an adhesive underneath the bb. If, somehow, you can connect the plate to your circuit ground then it *may* work as a crude shield.

Answer (score 0):

With the breadboards I've inspected, the backside and the contact stripes are just covered by adhesive and a sheet of paper.
A metal sheet may provide additional mechanical protection and provide resilience to fluids - ever knocked over a mug?

If the packaging wasn't tight, fixing goods of density higher than the packaging's reduces the probability of the good damaging the packaging.

Comment: Imagine dropping a nail in a longer cardboard sleeve: if it is free to move longitudinally, the point may hit&damage something. Not so if the nail was glued to the sleeve.

Comment: I have knocked over a mug, but my imagination isn't good enough to see how a metal sheet would help the electronical circuit. It's so flat that any liquid just flows over it.

Answer (score 0):

The contact clips in these breadboards are inserted into molded slots
from the underside.   If you didn't have a firm backplate behind them,
component insertion force could push them loose.

Any surface that you want the board connected to would serve the
purpose, but if you don't  have a box ready, the utility plate
and the double stick tape or screws suffice to contain the loose
hardware.